# How to optimize SQL queries for BINARY(N)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a table (10 mio rows). For every record I need to have 480 flags (0, 1).

My solution is to have binary(60) field and use bit for each flag.

It seems not bad but the questions is: how to optimize queries?
I need to select records where some bits set to 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[fnBinarySet3] 
(@Value varbinary(60),@Position int)
RETURNS varbinary(60) AS  
BEGIN 
declare @retValue varbinary(60)

SELECT   @retValue=L + Convert(Binary(1),M | P) + R
FROM    (SELECT SubString(@Value,1,@Position / 8),
        SubString(@Value,  @Position / 8 + 1,   1)
    ,   SubString(@Value,  @Position / 8 + 2,60)
    ,   Power(2,@Position % 8)  )   X(L,M,R,P);

    return @retValue
END

GO
create table t
(
int_id int not null identity primary key,
banner binary(60)
)

declare @i int
set @i=1000
while @i>0
begin
    insert into t (banner) values(0x0);
    set @i = @i-1;
end
update t set banner= [dbo].[fnBinarySet3] (banner,int_id%48)

select top 100 * from t where <------- for example where 3 or 5 bit is 1
```

I do not see how I can use indexes.

Your advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter):

> ... is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. False positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not.

Create a hash int/bigint column, persisted computed as a bloom of your 480 bits. Index the computed column. Search on the index, the bloom will filter out all certain negatives (hopefully a significant part), the rest (hopefully a few) you'll have to scan them and find if they truly match the bit.

Comment: Thank you Remus, it sounds interesting to use BF. The only question is how to compute suitable hash for this kind of field.